# Why doesn't the database change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wonder why the database does not modify user value and post value. I wrote the same in ASP.NET Core and the database modified the user's reputation

```
        public void AddRatingPost(string userId, int postId)
        {
            var item = db.Ratings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId && x.PostId == postId);
            var postUserId = postService.GetPostById(postId).UserId;

            Rating rating = new Rating
            {
                UserId = userId,
                PostId = postId
            };
            if (item == null)
            {
                var user = userService.GetUserById(postUserId).Reputation++;
                var post = postService.GetPostById(postId).Reputation++;
                db.Ratings.Add(rating);

            }
            else
            {
                var user = userService.GetUserById(postUserId).Reputation--;
                var post = postService.GetPostById(postId).Reputation--;
                db.Ratings.Remove(item);

            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This is UserService

```
    public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db;

        public UserService(ApplicationDbContext _db)
        {
            db = _db;
        }
        public ApplicationUser GetUserById(string userId)
        {
           var item =  db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);
           return item;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug this code? Are you sure that this method has been called?

Comment: Yes, the method adds to the database a "rating" with correct data

Comment: in your post you said data does not get changed. in a comment you say that actually the data is modified. So there is no problem then ....

Comment: Adds but does not modify user and post

Comment: Yeah so what does `userService.GetUserById()` do? It probably returns a DTO, or is anyway not connected to your `db` instance. It helps if you read [ask] and explain your expectations in your question. You expect `var user = userService.GetUserById(postUserId).Reputation--`, followed by `db.SaveChanges()`, to decrease the reputation of said user by one?